# PDFJS drag and drop image and save

Tags: javascript, cakephp, pdf.js

Greeting,
I have been required to make a module for a website I am working where user can drag and drop some image on a previewed pdf. So I found a sample code in codepen:

[Demo](https://codepen.io/ValerioEmanuele/pen/pGRZqe)

This is done using PDFJS. As far as I understand PDFJS is completely viewer. So my question is how can I finally save the modified page after I drag and drop the image over canvas previewed page. Does PDF-Lib with the combination of PDFJS is doable for this? Or TCPDF or other backend PHP based library would needed for this purpose.
Note: Backed is done in CakePHP.

```js
var pdfData = atob($('#pdfBase64').val());
 /*
 *  costanti per i placaholder 
 */
var maxPDFx = 595;
var maxPDFy = 842;
var offsetY = 7;
 
'use strict';


// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
//
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js';

  //
  // Asynchronous download PDF
  //
  var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
  loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    //
    // Fetch the first page
    //
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
      var scale = 1.0;
      var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
      //
      // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
      //
      var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      //
      // Render PDF page into canvas context
      //
      var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
      };
      //page.render(renderContext);
      
      page.render(renderContext).then(function() {
          $(document).trigger("pagerendered");
        }, function() {
          console.log("ERROR");
        });
      
    });
  });

  
  /* The dragging code for '.draggable' from the demo above
   * applies to this demo as well so it doesn't have to be repeated. */

  // enable draggables to be dropped into this
  interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
    // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
    accept: '.drag-drop',
    // Require a 100% element overlap for a drop to be possible
    overlap: 1,

    // listen for drop related events:

    ondropactivate: function (event) {
      // add active dropzone feedback
      event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
    },
    ondragenter: function (event) {
      var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
          dropzoneElement = event.target;

      // feedback the possibility of a drop
      dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
      draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
      draggableElement.classList.remove('dropped-out');
      //draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
    },
    ondragleave: function (event) {
      // remove the drop feedback style
      event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
      event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
      event.relatedTarget.classList.add('dropped-out');
      //event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
    },
    ondrop: function (event) {
      //event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
    },
    ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
      // remove active dropzone feedback
      event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
      event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    }
  });

  interact('.drag-drop')
    .draggable({
      inertia: true,
      restrict: {
        restriction: "#selectorContainer",
        endOnly: true,
        elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
      },
      autoScroll: true,
      // dragMoveListener from the dragging demo above
      onmove: dragMoveListener,
    });
  
  
  function dragMoveListener (event) {
        var target = event.target,
            // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
            x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
            y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

        // translate the element
        target.style.webkitTransform =
        target.style.transform ='translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

        // update the posiion attributes
        target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
        target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
      }

      // this is used later in the resizing demo
      window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;

  $(document).bind('pagerendered', function (e) {
       $('#pdfManager').show();
       var parametri = JSON.parse($('#parameters').val());
         $('#parametriContainer').empty();
       renderizzaPlaceholder(0, parametri); 
    });
  
  function renderizzaPlaceholder(currentPage, parametri){
          var maxHTMLx = $('#the-canvas').width();
            var maxHTMLy = $('#the-canvas').height();
        
            var paramContainerWidth = $('#parametriContainer').width();
            var yCounterOfGenerated = 0;
            var numOfMaxItem = 25;
            var notValidHeight = 30;
            var y = 0;
            var x = 6;
            var page=0;
            

            var totalPages=Math.ceil(parametri.length/numOfMaxItem);
            
            for (i = 0; i < parametri.length; i++) {
                var param = parametri[i];
                var page = Math.floor(i/numOfMaxItem);
                var display= currentPage == page ? "block" : "none";
                
                if(i > 0 && i%numOfMaxItem == 0){
                    yCounterOfGenerated = 0;
                }

                var classStyle = "";
                var valore = param.valore;
                /*il placeholder non è valido: lo incolonna a sinistra*/
        
                if(i > 0 && i%numOfMaxItem == 0){
                    yCounterOfGenerated = 0;
                }

                var classStyle = "";
                var valore = param.valore;
                /*il placeholder non è valido: lo incolonna a sinistra*/
                y = yCounterOfGenerated;
                yCounterOfGenerated += notValidHeight;
                classStyle = "drag-drop dropped-out";


                
                $("#parametriContainer").append('<div class="'+classStyle+'" data-id="-1" data-page="'+page+'" data-toggle="'+valore+'" data-valore="'+valore+'" data-x="'+x+'" data-y="'+y+'" style="transform: translate('+x+'px, '+y+'px); display:'+display+'">  <span class="circle"></span><span class="descrizione">'+param.descrizione+' </span></div>');
            }
            
            y = notValidHeight * (numOfMaxItem+1);
            var prevStyle = "";
            var nextStyle = "";
            var prevDisabled = false;
            var nextDisabled = false;
            if(currentPage == 0){
                prevStyle = "disabled";
                prevDisabled = true;
            }
            
            if(currentPage >= totalPages-1 || totalPages == 1){
                nextDisabled=true;
                nextStyle="disabled";
            } 
            
            //Aggiunge la paginazione
            $("#parametriContainer").append('<ul id="pager" class="pager" style="transform: translate('+x+'px, '+y+'px); width:200px;"><li onclick="changePage('+prevDisabled+','+currentPage+',-1)" class="page-item '+prevStyle+'"><span>«</span></li><li onclick="changePage('+nextDisabled+','+currentPage+',1)" class="page-item '+nextStyle+'" style="margin-left:10px;"><span>&raquo;</span></li></ul>');
            
     }
  
    function renderizzaInPagina(parametri){
        var maxHTMLx = $('#the-canvas').width();
        var maxHTMLy = $('#the-canvas').height();
    
        var paramContainerWidth = $('#parametriContainer').width();
        var yCounterOfGenerated = 0;
        var numOfMaxItem = 26;
        var notValidHeight = 30;
        var y = 0;
        var x = 6;
        for (i = 0; i < parametri.length; i++) {
            var param = parametri[i];
            
            var classStyle = "drag-drop can-drop";
            var valore = param.valore;
            /*il placeholder non è valido: lo incolonna a sinistra*/
            
            var pdfY = maxPDFy - param.posizioneY - offsetY;
            y = (pdfY * maxHTMLy) / maxPDFy;
            x = ((param.posizioneX * maxHTMLx) / maxPDFx) + paramContainerWidth;
    
            $("#parametriContainer").append('<div class="'+classStyle+'" data-id="'+param.idParametroModulo+'" data-toggle="'+valore+'" data-valore="'+valore+'" data-x="'+x+'" data-y="'+y+'" style="transform: translate('+x+'px, '+y+'px);">  <span class="circle"></span><span class="descrizione">'+param.descrizione+' </span></div>');
        }
    }
     
     
     function changePage(disabled, currentPage, delta){
         if(disabled){
            return;  
         }

         /*recupera solo i parametri non posizionati in pagina*/
         var parametri = [];
         $(".drag-drop.dropped-out").each(function() {
            var valore = $(this).data("valore");
            var descrizione = $(this).find(".descrizione").text();
            parametri.push({valore:valore, descrizione:descrizione, posizioneX:-1000, posizioneY:-1000});
            $(this).remove();
         });
         
         //svuota il contentitore
         $('#pager').remove();
         currentPage += delta;
         renderizzaPlaceholder(currentPage, parametri);
         //aggiorna lo stato dei pulsanti
         //aggiorna gli elementi visualizzati
     }

  
  function showCoordinates(){
    var validi = [];
      var nonValidi = [];
      
      var maxHTMLx = $('#the-canvas').width();
      var maxHTMLy = $('#the-canvas').height();
      var paramContainerWidth = $('#parametriContainer').width();
      
      //recupera tutti i placholder validi
      $('.drag-drop.can-drop').each(function( index ) {
          var x = parseFloat($(this).data("x"));
          var y = parseFloat($(this).data("y"));
          var valore = $(this).data("valore");
          var descrizione = $(this).find(".descrizione").text();
            
          var pdfY = y * maxPDFy / maxHTMLy;
          var posizioneY = maxPDFy - offsetY - pdfY;      
          var posizioneX =  (x * maxPDFx / maxHTMLx)  - paramContainerWidth;
          
          var val = {"descrizione": descrizione, "posizioneX":posizioneX,   "posizioneY":posizioneY, "valore":valore};
          validi.push(val);
      
      });
    
      if(validi.length == 0){
         alert('No placeholder dragged into document');
      }
     else{
      alert(JSON.stringify(validi));
     }
  }
```

```css
#messageContainer{
    display:none;
}

#outer-dropzone {
  height: 140px;

  touch-action: none;
}

#inner-dropzone {
  height: 80px;
}

.dropzone {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: dashed 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.drop-active {
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.drop-target {
  background-color: #29e;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
}

.drag-drop {
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  min-width: 40px;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  padding-left:0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #29e;
  border: none;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);

  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}

.drag-drop.can-drop {
  color: #000;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity:0.9;
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.9;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
}

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #323c3c;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.dropped-out{
    display: block;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    width:200px;
    color: black;
}

.col-fixed-240{
    width:240px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.col-fixed-605{
    margin-left:240px;
    width:605px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.page-item{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.pager{
    margin-bottom:30px !important;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    margin-bottom: -31px !important;
}

.drag-drop.dropped-out .descrizione {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

#the-canvas{
  height:842px;
  width: 595px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick="showCoordinates()">Show PDF Placeholders Coordinates</button>
      </div>
  </div>   
  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="pdfManager" style="display:none">    
                        <div class="row" id="selectorContainer">
                            <div class="col-fixed-240" id="parametriContainer">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-fixed-605">
                                <div id="pageContainer" class="pdfViewer singlePageView dropzone nopadding" style="background-color:transparent">
                                    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px  solid black"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>

<!-- parameters showed on the left sidebar -->
<input id="parameters" type="hidden" value='[{"idParametro":480,"descrizione":"RAPINA","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":481,"descrizione":"CAUSAL_G00","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":482,"descrizione":"A","valore":"A","nota":null},{"idParametro":483,"descrizione":"POSTA_REGISTRATA","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":484,"descrizione":"CD","valore":"CD","nota":null},{"idParametro":485,"descrizione":"DATA_ALERT","valore":"data alert","nota":null},{"idParametro":486,"descrizione":"UP","valore":"UP","nota":null},{"idParametro":488,"descrizione":"DATA_MP","valore":"DATA1","nota":null},{"idParametro":489,"descrizione":"AL_QUALITA","valore":"AL_QUALITA","nota":null},{"idParametro":490,"descrizione":"CAUSAL_G60","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":491,"descrizione":"DATA","valore":"DATA","nota":null},{"idParametro":492,"descrizione":"DATA_DENUNCIA","valore":"data denuncia","nota":null},{"idParametro":493,"descrizione":"DATA_SPEDIZIONE","valore":"data spedizione","nota":null},{"idParametro":494,"descrizione":"DATA_LAVORAZIONE","valore":"DATA_LAVORAZIONE","nota":null},{"idParametro":495,"descrizione":"NUMERO_FAX","valore":"NUMERO_FAX","nota":null},{"idParametro":496,"descrizione":"SMARRIMENTO","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":497,"descrizione":"STRUTT_ACCETTAZIONE","valore":"STRUTT_ACCETTAZIONE","nota":null},{"idParametro":498,"descrizione":"FURTO","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":499,"descrizione":"BARCODE","valore":"BARCODE","nota":null},{"idParametro":502,"descrizione":"CAUSA_MAGGIORE","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":503,"descrizione":"PACCHI","valore":"X","nota":null},{"idParametro":504,"descrizione":"TIPOLOGIA_EVENTO","valore":"TIPOLOGIA_EVENTO","nota":null},{"idParametro":505,"descrizione":"NOTE","valore":"NOTE","nota":null},{"idParametro":506,"descrizione":"DATA_RITROVAMENTO","valore":"data ritrovamento","nota":null},{"idParametro":507,"descrizione":"DATA_ACCETTAZIONE","valore":"DATA_ACCETTAZIONE","nota":null},{"idParametro":509,"descrizione":"AREA_LOGISTICA","valore":"AREA_LOGISTICA","nota":null},{"idParametro":511,"descrizione":"DA","valore":"DA","nota":null},{"idParametro":512,"descrizione":"DATA_DENUNCIA","valore":"DATA_DENUNCIA","nota":null},{"idParametro":513,"descrizione":"TIPOLOGIA_ALERT","valore":"TIPOLOGIA","nota":null},{"idParametro":515,"descrizione":"STRUTTURA_RILIEVO","valore":"STRUTTURA_RILIEVO","nota":null},{"idParametro":516,"descrizione":"STRUTTURA_DENUNCIA","valore":"STRUTTURA_DENUNCIA","nota":null},{"idParametro":517,"descrizione":"DISPACCIO","valore":"DISPACCIO","nota":null},{"idParametro":518,"descrizione":"CMP_CP","valore":"CMP_CP","nota":null},{"idParametro":520,"descrizione":"FURTO_EFFRAZIONE","valore":"X","nota":null}]' />
<!-- Below the pdf base 64 rapresentation -->
<input id="pdfBase64" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Thanks